# Unity fails to build due to IL2CPP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, il2cpp, nintendo-3ds

I made a archive of Unity for New 3DS, trying to use it myself tho it appears to give these errors even tho i have IL2CPP installed
SETUP:
Unity - 5.6.5f1 (New3DS key)
Build - New3DS
Ram - 8GB
CPU - I5

Error(s):

1:

```
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04 for Nintendo
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 5 Extended Maintenance (build 231)
Tool: armcc [4ce830]armcc : error C9555:  License checkout for feature bsp_compiler5 with version 5.0201509 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -10
Feature has expired.
Feature:       bsp_compiler5
Expire date:   25-may-2016
License path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\ARMCC_Nintendo_5\sw\info\nintendo-anyhost.lic;c:\program files\arm\licenses\license.dat;
FlexNet Licensing error:-10,32
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NativeCompiler:RunProgram(ProcessStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:57)
NativeCompiler:Execute(String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:24)
ArmccCompiler:Compile(String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:195)
<CompileDynamicLibrary>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:101)
<ParallelFor>c__AnonStorey1`1:<>m__0(Object) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:86)
```

2:

```
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04 for Nintendo
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 5 Extended Maintenance (build 231)
Tool: armcc [4ce830]armcc : error C9555:  License checkout for feature bsp_compiler5 with version 5.0201509 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -10
Feature has expired.
Feature:       bsp_compiler5
Expire date:   25-may-2016
License path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\ARMCC_Nintendo_5\sw\info\nintendo-anyhost.lic;c:\program files\arm\licenses\license.dat;
FlexNet Licensing error:-10,32
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NativeCompiler:RunProgram(ProcessStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:57)
NativeCompiler:Execute(String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:24)
ArmccCompiler:Compile(String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:195)
<CompileDynamicLibrary>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:101)
<ParallelFor>c__AnonStorey1`1:<>m__0(Object) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:86)
```

3:

```
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04 for Nintendo
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 5 Extended Maintenance (build 231)
Tool: armcc [4ce830]armcc : error C9555:  License checkout for feature bsp_compiler5 with version 5.0201509 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -10
Feature has expired.
Feature:       bsp_compiler5
Expire date:   25-may-2016
License path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\ARMCC_Nintendo_5\sw\info\nintendo-anyhost.lic;c:\program files\arm\licenses\license.dat;
FlexNet Licensing error:-10,32
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NativeCompiler:RunProgram(ProcessStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:57)
NativeCompiler:Execute(String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:24)
ArmccCompiler:Compile(String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:195)
<CompileDynamicLibrary>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:101)
<ParallelFor>c__AnonStorey1`1:<>m__0(Object) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:86)
```

4:

```
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04 for Nintendo
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 5 Extended Maintenance (build 231)
Tool: armcc [4ce830]armcc : error C9555:  License checkout for feature bsp_compiler5 with version 5.0201509 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -10
Feature has expired.
Feature:       bsp_compiler5
Expire date:   25-may-2016
License path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\ARMCC_Nintendo_5\sw\info\nintendo-anyhost.lic;c:\program files\arm\licenses\license.dat;
FlexNet Licensing error:-10,32
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NativeCompiler:RunProgram(ProcessStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:57)
NativeCompiler:Execute(String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:24)
ArmccCompiler:Compile(String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:195)
<CompileDynamicLibrary>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__1(String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:101)
<ParallelFor>c__AnonStorey1`1:<>m__0(Object) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:86)
```

5:

```
Product: ARM Compiler 5.04 for Nintendo
Component: ARM Compiler 5.04 update 5 Extended Maintenance (build 231)
Tool: armcc [4ce830]armcc : error C9555:  License checkout for feature bsp_compiler5 with version 5.0201509 has been denied by Flex back-end. Error code: -10
Feature has expired.
Feature:       bsp_compiler5
Expire date:   25-may-2016
License path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\ARMCC_Nintendo_5\sw\info\nintendo-anyhost.lic;c:\program files\arm\licenses\license.dat;
FlexNet Licensing error:-10,32
For further information, refer to the FlexNet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.flexerasoftware.com".
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
NativeCompiler:RunProgram(ProcessStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:57)
NativeCompiler:Execute(String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/NativeCompiler.cs:24)
ArmccCompiler:Compile(String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:195)
ArmccCompiler:CreateLinkInfo(String[], String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:307)
ArmccCompiler:CompileDynamicLibrary(String, IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/N3DS/Editor/Managed/ArmccCompiler.cs:103)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:161)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:41)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

6:

```
  at NativeCompiler.RunProgram (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x000e6] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\NativeCompiler.cs:59 
  at NativeCompiler.Execute (System.String arguments, System.String compilerPath) [0x00012] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\NativeCompiler.cs:24 
  at ArmccCompiler.Compile (System.String file, System.String includePaths, Boolean force) [0x0016e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\PlatformDependent\N3DS\Editor\Managed\ArmccCompiler.cs:195 
  at ArmccCompiler.CreateLinkInfo (System.String[] sources, System.String includePaths) [0x00230] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\PlatformDependent\N3DS\Editor\Managed\ArmccCompiler.cs:307 
  at ArmccCompiler.CompileDynamicLibrary (System.String outputFile, IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 includePaths, IEnumerable`1 libraries, IEnumerable`1 libraryPaths) [0x001af] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\PlatformDependent\N3DS\Editor\Managed\ArmccCompiler.cs:103 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () [0x00105] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:161 
  at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry, Boolean debugBuild) [0x0000f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:41 
  at UnityEditor.PostProcessN3DS.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, BuildOptions options, System.String installPath, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String stagingAreaDataManaged, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) [0x00146] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\PlatformDependent\N3DS\Editor\Managed\PostProcessN3DS.cs:200 
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

followed by:
`Error building Player: 6 errors`

Keep in mind i have IL2CPP installed and the New3DS as a build option, i have no idea what to do, im gonna add a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnsjU.png) for good measures, please try to help...

Comment: It seems that the armcc can't find a proper licence and therefore does not build what ever you try to build. Maybe that is also causing the problem with IL2CPP.

Comment: Are you a registered Nintendo developer? https://developer.nintendo.com/ I did see this on the developer website but not sure what it means. "Distribution of Unity for Wii U and New Nintendo 3DS has ended."

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? And then searching for it on Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under ARMCC_License you have to run the .bat file, this will register the software!